# Why this program ( open encodings utf-8 utf-8-sig ) fails in some context, not in other context

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

Why, with this program :

```py
import sys

print("sys.getdefaultencoding()='%s'" % (sys.getdefaultencoding(), ))

with open("example.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", errors="replace") as f:
    f.write("test;Ilość sztuk\n")

with open("example.txt", "r", errors="strict") as rf:
    lr = rf.readline()
    print("lr=", lr)
```

run OK in some context, and failed in other context.

example OK :

```
$ python3 ./example.py 
sys.getdefaultencoding()='utf-8'
lr= ﻿test;Ilość sztuk
```

note :

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

example KO :

```
sys.getdefaultencoding()='utf-8'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 9, in <module>
    lr = rf.readline()
  File "/.../python/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
$
```

note :

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Contexts are ; Ubuntu 19.04, Ubuntu 18.04, Debian 9, in chroot, outside chroot, LANG is "en_US.UTF-8" or "fr_FR.UTF-8", no impact on success or failed

In all case, Python is install by hand with same option.

If you need value of some environment variable, I can give it.

I search to have exact same execution in all case.

Comment: How are you transporting the program itself between the different environments? Did you just copy / send the file, or are you copying and pasting content between machines? I.e. are you sure the encoding of the source file is the same between systems?

Comment: I have remove this line in question : # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ,. I always put this line, and program are propagate by git on different machine

Comment: If you use `open()` without the `encoding=...` parameter, its default is read from `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, not `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) (10th paragraph approximately).

Comment: Lenz, with locale.getpreferredencoding(), I have the answer that I looking for ! It's "UTF-8" in one case, "ANSI_X3.4-1968" in other case. If you put this in a answer, I will vote for "My answer" !

Comment: A dpkg-reconfigure locale solved my problem. Now, program run correctly in all case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, there are different encoding defaults.
The one you found, [`sys.getdefaultencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding), tells you the default for the methods `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()`.
As far as I know, it's always UTF-8, no matter what build or implementation of Python you use.

However, if you omit the `encoding=...` parameter in a call to `open()`, then [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) is used; also for `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` (`print()`!), `sys.stderr`.
The value of this default depends on the environment in which the Python interpreter is started.
The details of how this value is determined varies between platforms, but often you can achieve the desired behaviour by setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` env variable.
As of Python 3.7, you can launch Python with `-X utf8` to enable UTF-8 mode.